# Content Blur when zoom it using iscroll

Tags: javascript, css, iscroll

In iScroll the zoom function, when zoom in the items within gets blurry. Is there any way to resolve such an issue? Many thanks!

Comment: plz post ur code or fiddle

Comment: Please check with zooming
http://lab.cubiq.org/iscroll5/demos/zoom/